# A set for which the majority have a common theme

Tags: wordplay, anagram, connections-puzzle

Sometimes it's fun to be a little too literal.

> 1. The family being pushed repeatedly.
> 2. The reach of a ring.
> 3. Electricity of darkness.
> 4. The gradual destruction of transportation.
> 5. Unable to marry alone.
> 6. Some masculine leaves.
> 7. Repeating dogs feet.
> 8. Monkey returns to the crib.

These eight all refer to objects that belong in a single set. But one is different from the others and thus there are two distinct subsets (one of which has just one element)... and if you've figured it out, you'll know it, because one of them epitomises the larger subset.

Now, you do need to find the word describing seven of the eight. But that's just leading into the next step. Drop the last letter, and you'll get an anagram of something that belongs to a set of six things, and is the third of that set.

Your task is to identify the number associated with that "third of six" object.

**Note** - To be clear, only the clues to the eight members of the set are "too literal". I have not hidden "too literal" clues elsewhere in the question.

Comment: @leoll2 - "epitomise" is just as correct as "epitomize", just European English instead of American English :-)

Comment: I'm going to nominate this for one of the best puzzles of the 2nd quarter of 2015.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Full answer

The theme of the 8 clues is

> fruit and vegetables.

Here they all are:

> 1. **Pumpkin** (pushed repeatedly = pump, family = kin) - credit to **leoll2** for this one
> 2. **Orange** (ring = o, reach = range)
> 3. **Blackcurrant** (electricity ~ currant, darkness = black) - credit to **Hubble07** for this one
> 4. **Carrot** (transportation = car, gradual destruction = rot)
> 5. **Canteloupe** (unable to = can't, marry = elope)
> 6. **Mangoes** (masculine = man, leaves = goes)
> 7. **Pawpaws** (dog feet = paws, repeated).
> 8. **Apricot** (monkey = ape, return ~ ri, crib = cot)

Seven of them (all except #3) have the following property in common (which is epitomised by #2):

> they're all **orange**.

Drop the last letter of this property to get

> orang,

which is an anagram of

> argon,

which is the third of the six

> noble gases

and has

> atomic number 18.

So the final answer is **18**.

### Brilliant puzzle!

Comment: I believe you for 1 and 8. Return = re ~ ri, ma = mother ~ family.

Comment: I will reveal that you have five (not number 5, but five of them) right. I won't say which, yet.

Comment: @GlenO I think 2,4,6,7,8 are right. Maybe the odd one out is 4 for not being a fruit?

Comment: @GlenO And now 5 - very nice one!

Comment: Number #1 is Pumpkin; Push=Pump, Kin=relatives

Comment: @randal'thor - if that's true (not being a fruit), which one epitomises being a fruit?

Comment: Number #3 is blackcurrants

Comment: @Hubble07 - well done on picking that one up. Otherwise, Lews Therin has it right.

Comment: @GlenO Solved! Thanks to leoll2 and Hubble07 for solving two of the eight clues.

Comment: @GlenO No no, [this](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/10399/double-whammy-murder-case-what-happened/10401#comment34571_10401) is Lews Therin ;-) Brilliant puzzle BTW - I really enjoyed it!

Comment: @randal'thor - oh, I had seen you, and Ishamael, but I didn't realise that Lews Therin had his own account.

Comment: Also... @leoll2 - Well done, picking up on Pumpkin (worth noting that the "repeatedly" is there to emphasise that it's not just a singular push, but multiple, as would happen when pumping something). By the way, "epitomise" is the Australian/British spelling.

Comment: Oh, by the way... did you notice the extra reference to the answer I threw into the title? 18 in most English-speaking countries is the age of...?

Comment: @GlenO Ha, nice one! :-)

Comment: But mangoes are yellow, not orange. :(

Comment: @IanMacDonald - that might be a regional variation thing. Most mangoes I know are orange. http://www.sevenfields.com.au/media/5914/kp%20mango%20240%20pix.jpg - note, though, that I made certain that the odd one out was very not-orange, because I knew some might stray a little close to "yellow" or "red" in certain variants.

Comment: Just for reference, [this is the colour of mango](http://st1.travel.india.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/mango.jpg) I usually get (in Canada).

Comment: If I ever need someone for a think tank I'm picking you

Comment: @mascaliente I'll take that as a compliment...

Comment: @randal'thor you should! Absolutely brilliant! Haha